# ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION 1 (0x1)

Tags: visual-c++, winapi, console

I'm having this weird error with my application that is supposed to copy files from a directory given from the command line to another directory.

I'm using of course the three API functions; CreateFile, ReadFile, and WriteFile. I can't use the CopyFile API.

Note that the compiler doesn't report any errors nor any warnings.

```
hFile1 = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL); 

hSearch = FindFirstFile((L"*.*"), &hFind); 
if (hSearch == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { _tprintf(L"No files found.\n"); }

do 
{
  if (ReadFile(hFile1, Buffer, BUFSIZE, &BytesRead, NULL))
  {

    cFile = WriteFile(hFile2, Buffer, BytesRead, &BytesWritten, NULL);
    if (!cFile)
    {
      _tprintf(L"Couldn't copy file.\n");
    }

  }
} while (BUFSIZE == BytesRead);
```

Comment: Please add more detail. Can you show us a snippet of the code that's giving you trouble? Which function is returning 0x1?

Comment: And why can't you use CopyFile?

Comment: I can't use CopyFile beacuse that the assignment. I'll post a snippet when I finish backing up my Ubuntu :)